# How can I convert a pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame back to a sql table in databricks notebook

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I created a dataframe of type `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` by executing the following line:
`dataframe = sqlContext.sql("select * from my_data_table")`

How can I convert this back to a sparksql table that I can run sql queries on?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create your table by using [createReplaceTempView](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=sql#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView). In your case it would be like:

```
dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")
```

After this you can query your `mytable` using *SQL*.

If your a spark version is ≤ 1.6.2 you can use [registerTempTable](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.registerTempTable)

Comment: When I run `dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")` 
I get the following error:
 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'createOrReplaceTempView'

Comment: What version of Apache spark are you using?

Comment: If you want to permanently create a table use this `df.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("mytable")`

Comment: Use following to first drop the table if exists and then create one `  spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName)`